# Unknown provider: $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I can't really get my head around why this markup doesn't recognize my $stateProvider?

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due
to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
```

Simple module:

```
(function () {
   'use strict';
// get modules we need for the app
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$stateProvider']

function config($stateProvider) {
    console.log('works'); // actually doesn't
};

})();
```

I've tried various other styles 
eg loading them straight in the config

```
 .config(['$stateProvider'], function ($stateProvider) {
  // not working this way either.
  });
```

Comment: try `.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {...}])` you were having `]` before function in second style you mentioned

Comment: `angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
      .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
      }]);` this is causing the same error.

Comment: Must be some other issue then. make sure you actually have `$stateProvider` available.. script not loaded yet or some typo in script src?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `ngRoute` in that way you have to use the `$routeProvider`. The `$stateProvider` is based on `ui-router`. Please check this [runnable fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mhs8mja/4/) and switch to `$routeProver` or use `ui-router` in combination with `$stateProvier`.

---

#### [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) configuration

This is a [runnable fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mhs8mja/4/) of `ngRoute` implementation.

```
/* App Module */
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function( $routeProvider) {

     // Define routes 
     $routeProvider.when('/homepage', { 
         templateUrl: 'partial/homepage.html',
         controller: HomePageCtrl
       }).when('/users', { 
         templateUrl: 'partial/users.html',
         controller: UsersListCtrl
       }).when('/contacts',{ 
         templateUrl: 'partial/contacts.html',
         controller: ContactPageCtrl
       }).otherwise({
         redirectTo: 'homepage'
       });
   }
]);
```

---

#### [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) configuration

This is a [runnable fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7ncej74/) of `ui-route` implementation.

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",["ui.router"])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
      $stateProvider.state("state1", {
          url: "#",
          template: "<p>State 1</p>",
          controller: "Ctrl1"
        }).state("state2", {
          url: "#",
          template: "<p>State 2</p>",
          controller: "Ctrl2"
        });
});
```

Comment: This was correct, I was using ngRoute in a hurry when I should have been using angular-ui-router and the problem was fixed. Thank you.

Comment: @poptard glad to help you.